# Review extended List<> functionality

Tags: c#, refactoring

I was curious if I could enhance the standard generic `List<>` functionality because I was fed up with writing code such as:

```
var list = new List<Person>{
     new Person{Name = "David", Age = 24},
     new Person{Name = "John", Age = 30}
 };
list.Add(new Person{Name = "Terry", Age = 28});
```

I'd prefer that `T` could be implicitly constructed. The best I came up with allowed me to do this with up to four object construction parameters:

```
  var list = new ListWithConstructor<string, int, Person>(
                (name,age) => new Person { Name = name, Age = age })
  {
       {"David", 24},
       {"John", 30}
  };          
  list.Add("Terry", 28);
```

This is implemented like this:

```
public class ListWithConstructor<T1, T> : List<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T1, T> itemConstructor;
    public ListWithConstructor(Func<T1, T> itemConstructor)
    {
        this.itemConstructor = itemConstructor;
    }

    public void Add(T1 arg1)
    {
        base.Add(itemConstructor(arg1));
    }
}

public class ListWithConstructor<T1, T2, T> : List<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T1, T2, T> itemConstructor;
    public ListWithConstructor(Func<T1, T2, T> itemConstructor)
    {
        this.itemConstructor = itemConstructor;
    }

    public void Add(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
    {
        base.Add(itemConstructor(arg1, arg2));
    }
}
```

...and so on for up to four arguments.

Obviously the other `List<>` constructors (taking a capacity and an `IEnumerable` of existing elements) can be implemented as well.

How can this be improved?

Comment: Why are you writing a lot of code like that anyway?

Comment: The question is based on curiosity - seemed fairly harmless, didn't realise I'd get such a ridiculous response from what used to be a supportive community.

Comment: You stated "I was fed up with writing code such as...." That doesn't seem like merely a curiosity. Additionally, characterizing a response as "ridiculous" does not seem to be actively participating as a member of said "supportive community."

Comment: @Jason - neither is dismissing a question as nonsense. The third word of my question is "curious"...I honestly was just curious and was attacked by some arrogant dev. The fact that it's not a good idea and violates SRP is perfectly reasonable but the original answer was **This can't be improved. It really is nonsense.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality that you are looking for is (almost) already available at your fingertips:

```
var names = new[] { "David", "John" };
var persons = new List<Person>(names.Select(name => new Person { Name = name }));
```

This way you also have a clear separation of concerns; the `List` is not at all involved in the object construction (not even by just invoking a delegate), but is simply assigned a sequence of objects. The transformation is taken care of separately.

This can also handle the case of transforming multiple values into single objects:

```
public static IList<Person> GetListFromNamesAndAges(string[] names, int[] ages)
{
    if (names.Length != ages.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("names and ages must be of equal length.");
    }

    return new List<Person>(
        names.Select((name, index) =>
            new Person { Name = name, Age = ages[index] }));
}

// usage example:
var persons = GetListFromNamesAndAges(
    new[] {"David", "John"}, 
    new[] {24, 30});
```

In the case of merging values from exactly two lists into single objects, using `Zip` might give slightly cleaner code;

```
return names
    .Zip(ages, (name, age) => new Person {Name = name, Age = age})
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it like this. You are violating the "Separation Of Concerns" principle.
Why don't you just declare an implicit conversion from `string` to `Person` for the case with one constructor parameter?

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Person(string name)
    {
        return new Person(name);
    }
}

var list = new List<Person>();
list.Add("Terry");
```

To be able to shorten the code for adding an object with multiple constructor parameters, I think you should do the following:
Use the `Func` you created directly in the call to `Add`:

```
Func<string, string, Person> ctor = 
    (firstName, name) => new Person { Name = name, FirstName = firstName };
list.Add(ctor("Terry", "McDouglas"));
list.Add(ctor("Jones", "Miller"));
```

This is **a lot** cleaner.

Comment: I'm sure I alluded clearly to passing more than one argument in to construct the object.

Comment: It still is nonsense. You are mixing responsibilities here.

Comment: Not at all - the consuming code retains control of the how the initialization occurs.

Comment: The list creates the objects it then stores. This clearly is a mix of responsibilities.

Comment: @David: Please see update for discussion of the case with multiple constructor parameters. I also re-phrased it to be less harsh. Sorry for that.